# How can I register an already uploaded unmanaged file as managed file?

Tags: 8, files

I am stuck in a point that should be easy but I couldn't figure it out.

To make a long story short; I uploaded manually some images to the public directory and now I want to register them as managed files but I am stuck for some time where I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I tried using `system_retrieve_file` but it seems to accept only URLs not local paths `public://` as it uses cURL to get the file

Also, I tried using `file_save_data` with no luck as well for the same mentioned points.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new managed file, pretty easy as the following:

```
$user = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
    $image = File::create([
    'uri' => $image_local_path,
    'uid' => $user,
    'status' => FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT,
  ]);
  $image->save();
```